# How can we expose a form to user without writing custom code in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I want to create a form which is available to users just like contact form in drupal 7. Where user can fill in the details and submit the form. Can we do that without writing custom code. i.e.., just by using drupal 7 content types, block etc....

Answer (score 2):

there's a module called [webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform).

Comment: I have gone through the webform module... But can we execute our own submit handler when the user clicks the submit button.

Comment: I thought you said you don't wanna write custom code. If you want to write custom code, it's easy to write your own module or extend others. Or you could combine both: create your form with webform then hook into the submit handler and do your additional submit stuff there :)